# Web Intelligence : input control calendar and empty var

Tags: business-objects, webi

I know how to create an empty text var in webi depending input control (using ="" formula). I tried to apply this for dates but I can't select calendar control.

How can I create an empty date var linked to a calendar input control ?

**Update :**

First I create the date type var

[image]

Then I create the input control. I don't have the same interface maybe because of the french version or the support pack difference ?

[image]

Finally I update my var

[image]

Comment: It looks like you are doing everything how I described. I don't know why it isn't working. I am sorry, I do not know what else to have you try.

Comment: You could try posting this question on [SAP.com](https://answers.sap.com/tags/907900296036854683333078008146613) and maybe get some additional exposure. If you do, post the link here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly not intuitive, but I think this will work for you.

Begin by creating a variable with a value or formula that is a date data type. I called my variable **Input Control Date**.

```
=CurrentDate()
```

This would also work.

```
=ToDate("06/03/2020"; "MM/dd/yyyy")
```

[image]

We will change this later. The reason for this is so that WebI will give you the option of creating an input control with a calendar date picker.

Create your input control based on **Input Control Date**.

[image]

I think you would want to set the **Dependencies** to "Whole Document", but you may want to change that based on your specific situation.

Now that you have created your input control with the calendar control to choose the date  you can go back and change the value of **Input Control Date** to an empty string.

```
=""
```

If you want to be able to format your chosen date value (or compare it to an object with a   date data type) you will need to create another variable and convert it to a date since Input Control Date is not a string and cannot be formatted. That would look like this.

```
=ToDate([Input Control Date]; "MM/dd/yyyy")
```

[image]

And now a format can be applied.

[image]

Comment: I tried your solution but my var "Input Control Date" display nothing ("Converted Date" also) ... Maybe because of my version ? I'm on Version 4.2 SP4.

Comment: I am on 4.1 SP6 Patch 4. I suppose I might be taking advantage of a loophole that has since been closed. I have a 4.2 SP7 test system. I'll try it there and let you know.

Comment: It works for me. Can you edit your question and post screen shots what each variable and the input control definition?